# know if an Optional parameter is not filled in function invoke VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, parameters

ok I do have this kind of function

```
Public Function myDog(name As String, age As Integer,Optional color As String = Nothing) As String
   'todo codes
    return Nothing
End Sub
```

now my problem is I want to know inside my function how can I find that parameter `color` was not filled during function invoke

```
myDog("brown",2)
```

now I really don't want to rely if parameter `color` holds `Nothing` then its not filled during the function invoke. I really want to know if the function is invoked and filled up until parameter `color`

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly? Do you want to check in your function that whether parameter `color` holds any value?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to know if the optional parameter has been set during invocation of the method, you should use overloading for this.

I would replace your method with these 3 methods:

```
Public Function myDog(name As String, age As Integer) As String
    Return myDog(name, age, Nothing, False)
End Function

Public Function myDog(name As String, age As Integer, color As String) As String
    Return myDog(name, age, color, True)
End Function

Private Function myDog(name As String, age As Integer, color As String, filledColor As Boolean) As String
    'todo codes
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Please notice that only the first two methods are public accessible while the third will be private and do all the work. Inside the third you can then check if filledColor will be true.